# decouple differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have a system of two Second Order differential equations
$$
r^2 \ddot{r} - r^3(\dot{\varphi}^2 +\omega^2) =-GM
$$
$$
r \ddot{\varphi} + 2\dot{r}(\dot{\varphi}+\omega)=0
$$
which I am supposed to decouple using the conservation size $ (\dot{\varphi}+\omega)r^2 $ I have shown, that it is indeed a conservation size, as its derivation is r-times the second equation and therefore zero. However I don't know how this is supposed to help me decoupling the two equations.
I would be very thankful for hints.

Answer (score 0):

$$
r\varphi'' + 2r'(\varphi'+\omega)=0\quad\to\quad \frac{\varphi'' }{\varphi'+\omega}=-2\frac{r'}{r}
$$
$$\ln|\varphi'+\omega|=-2\ln[r|+c$$
$$\varphi'=\frac{C}{r^2}-\omega$$
$$
r^2 r' - r^3((\varphi')^2 +\omega^2) =-GM=
r^2 r' - r^3\left(\frac{C}{r^2}-\omega\right)^2 -r^3\omega^2 
$$
$$ r' = r\left(\frac{C}{r^2}-\omega\right)^2 +r\omega^2-\frac{GM}{r^2}$$
$$\frac{dr}{dt}= r' = \frac{C^2}{r^3}-\frac{GM}{r^2} -\frac{2C\omega}{r}+2r\omega^2$$
$$t=\int \frac{dr}{\frac{C^2}{r^3}-\frac{GM}{r^2} -\frac{2C\omega}{r}+2r\omega^2}+c_1$$
This integral can be analytically solved. This would be a arduous task, involving a quartic polynomial equation to be solved and then separating the polynomial fraction into four elementary fractions which are each integrable. Too long to be done here.

$$\frac{d\varphi}{dt}=\frac{C}{r^2}-\omega \quad\to\quad \frac{d\varphi}{dr}=(\frac{C}{r^2}-\omega)\frac{dr}{dt} $$
$$\frac{d\varphi}{dr}= (\frac{C}{r^2}-\omega)\left( \frac{C^2}{r^3}-\frac{GM}{r^2} -\frac{2C\omega}{r}+2r\omega^2\right) $$

$$\varphi(r)=\int (\frac{C}{r^2}-\omega)\left( \frac{C^2}{r^3}-\frac{GM}{r^2} -\frac{2C\omega}{r}+2r\omega^2\right) dr$$
This is easy to integrate (expand and integrate each elementary term).

So, the problem is solved on parametric form :

- The explicit function $\varphi(r)$
- The implicit function $t(r)$.

There is probably no closed form for the inverse function $r(t)$.